# Dynamically loading a script changes its behaviour

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, jquery-events, paperjs

I wanted `paperjs` to load after a button is pressed to turn on animations but it seems the paperscript doesn't work if paper is loaded after page load.

If you comment out the `setTimeout` and uncomment the direct `$.getScript` - paperjs will fire the `alert('hi')`. I don't get it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var paperUrl = 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.22/paper.js';
                $("#jq").text("jQuery is now loaded.")
                var lateLoad = function() {
                    $.getScript(paperUrl, function() {
                        $("#pp").text("Paperjs is now loaded.");
                    });
                };
                //setTimeout(lateLoad, 100);
                $.getScript(paperUrl, function() {
                    $("#pp").text("Paperjs is now loaded.");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
            $('body').css({"background-color": "#999"});
            alert('hi!');
        </script>
        <p id="jq">jQuery NOT loaded yet.</p>
        <p id="pp">Paperjs NOT loaded yet.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m on Windows 7 x64. Anybody have an idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured out a workaround as well - `paper.PaperScript.load()` or to elaborate:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#jq").text("jQuery is now loaded.")
                var paperUrl = 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.22/paper.js';
                var lateLoad = function() {
                    $.getScript(paper_url, function() { 
                        $("#pp").text("Paperjs is now loaded.");
                        paper.PaperScript.load(); // <-- The fix!
                    });
                };
                setTimeout(lateLoad, 1000);
                //$.getScript(paperUrl, function() {
                //    $("#pp").text("Paperjs is now loaded.");
                //});
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
            $('body').css({"background-color": "#999"});
            alert('hi!');
        </script>
        <p id="jq">jQuery NOT loaded yet.</p>
        <p id="pp">Paperjs NOT loaded yet.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

That causes paperscript to scan for all the paperscripts. I found it at https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/master/src/core/PaperScript.js#L270 while googling for "paperscript" in the github repo. Though it still doesn't explain why paper doesn't do the load() on its own when dynamically loaded.

**EDIT** - I understand what went wrong. It's related to https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L768 because paperjs doesn't check if the window loaded event had already fired i.e `document.readyState === "complete"`. I submitted a pull request to paperjs https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/pull/156

Comment: It would be good if you would add some line breaks in getScript and especially before paper.PaperScript.load();. Because I had to search the page for ".load" to understand what you did and where ;)

Comment: You're right, it took me quite a while to figure out as well. Fixed it now I hope. I only recently learned the node.js convention for callback indentation. What a beauty.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to load it via [require.js](http://requirejs.org/). All you need is a `require.config` object, defined in e.g. main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths : {   
        'jquery' : "path/to/jquery"
        'paper' : "path/to/paper"
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery' : {
            exports: 'jQuery'
        },
        'paper' : {
            exports: 'paper'
        }
    }
});
```

You will need to load require.js with the above config via the `data-main` attribute:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Then you define a module (e.g. 'paperStuff') where your paper logic will be:

```
define(['jquery', 'paper'], function($, paper) {
   // do some cool stuff
});
```

When you want to load your paperStuff, you just do

```
var paperStuff = require('paperStuff');
...
```

Comment: Quite the complex solution for loading scripts, jquery does it very well on its own. I'm not sure this fixes anything or that I'd like another javascript dependency...

Comment: Your script with alert('hi') will always be shown, since it is on global scope. You need to load it in the $.getScript() scope. Can't you store it in a separate file and load it with a 2nd getScript() call within the paperjs getScript load?

Comment: Did you notice `type="text/paperscript"`? Because that causes the browser to skip it and only paperjs executes it.

Comment: Ah ok. Never mind then. I don't use paperjs. Maybe if you load paperJs, it evaluates the page first before executing its loaded callback?

Answer (score 0):

Move your paperscript code into an external file (i.e. pstest.js) and modify your lateLoad to:

```
var lateLoad = function() {
    $.getScript('http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.22/paper.js',
    function() {
      $("#pp").text("Paperjs is now loaded.");
      $.getScript("pstest.js");
    } )
}
```