# paper.js Stroke Drawing Inconsistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, paperjs

I am having trouble not only fixing this issue but also reproducing it.  I have a web app with a lot going on but the problem I'm having with paper.js is that sometimes the stroke will draw way too large.  Here is how it should look:

[image: screenshot 2016-10-24 15 03 45]

But it draws like this:

[image: screenshot 2016-10-24 15 03 29]

Anyone have any clues how this could be happening?  It only shows up intermittently.  Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I have figured out that the problem originates from that I dynamically size my `<canvas>` element to fit the screen on load with jQuery.  I have now added an event that passes the height and width to my Paperscript, but it is not working still.  Will post solution as soon as I have it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from the canvas not being sized before PaperScript takes over, thus creating a tiny canvas that is then scaled up to fit the element.

The solution is to work on the timing of the PaperScript load.  I fixed it by modifying my loading code like so (shortened and "para-coded" for brevity):

```
$(document).ready(function() { // wait for elements to propagate
  $.get(...) // load html for text from external files
    .then($('images').waitForImages() // wait for images to load
      .then(function() {
         resizeCanvas(); // make the canvas the correct size

         $.getScript(paper_url, function() { // load paper.js dynamically
           console.log("Paperjs is now loaded.");
           paper.PaperScript.load(); // get paper.js to scan your application for paperscript
         });

         // do everything else post load
       });
     });
  });
});
```

I found this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14114337/1288913.  I hope it helps someone out there!